# Broken apt-get state after apache install error

Tags: 14.04, apt, apache2

I tried to install php5 via

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

on my ubuntu 14.04 machine. It didn't install properly, because there were problems with the package apache2.

So if I try to install anything, I just get

```
Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
libapache2-mod-php5 : Hängt ab von: apache2 (>= 2.4) soll aber nicht installiert werden
E: Unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten. Versuchen Sie »apt-get -f install« ohne Angabe eines Pakets (oder geben Sie eine Lösung an).
```

Or in english (roughly translated)

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libapache2-mod-php5 : Depending: apache2 (>= 2.4) but shall not be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try "apt-get -f install" without a package.
```

When I run the the recommended command, I get

```
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../apache2_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: Zeile 118: a2query: Kommando nicht gefunden.
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Archivs /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
Unterprozess neues pre-installation-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurück
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von: /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Again, a poor translation:

```
Preparing extraction .../apache2_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: Line 118: a2query: Command not found.
dpkg: Error with processing the archive /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
Subprocess new pre-installation-Skript returned error value 1
Errors occured while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix that now? Any installation requires me to finish this apache installation stuff, which never works. Any help appreciated.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: a2query exists in the apache2 package. Have you tried to install Apache before? Check this out, should solve your problem  http://superuser.com/questions/716194/cant-install-apache2-on-debian-jessie

Comment: Thanks @ElefantPhace, this link was useful. I don't remember having installed apache2 before, however the directory was there. Don't know why. Anyway, problem solved.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As ElefantPrice indicated in a comment, https://superuser.com/questions/716194/cant-install-apache2-on-debian-jessie has the solution.

There was an existing directory /etc/apache2 (actually, I don't know why). Deleted it, so it worked.

Answer (score 1):

View this thread https://superuser.com/questions/716194/cant-install-apache2-on-debian-jessie

And delete `/etc/apache2` if it exists

Or try this:

```
sudo dpkg --fsys-tarfile /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb | tar xOf - ./usr/sbin/a2query > /usr/sbin/a2query
sudo chmod 755 /usr/sbin/a2query
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This will pull a2query out of the .deb package you've already downloaded and place it where it needs to be with the correct permissions. Then do `install -f` again to fix broken dependencies

Comment: the first command gives (even with sudo, translation in cornered brackets) '"bash: /usr/sbin/a2query: Keine Berechtigung [no permission] dpkg-deb: Fehler: Unterprozess einfügen wurde durch Signal (Datenübergabe unterbrochen (broken pipe)) getötet [subprocess killed because of broken pipe]"'

Comment: Try adding `sudo` in front of `tar` after the pipe ( | )